# Is there a way to use Selenium with a page which HTML code is not public?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm trying to use Selenium automation but the web page I'm working on doesn't show its HTML code when I try to inspect it.

I've tried to use the information that I have access to but no results so far

Here is a snippet of what I have acces to on the login page:

```
<body scroll="no" style="margin: 0px;" onfocus="gotFocus()">
<div id="webuidiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 50;">
<embed name="Framework" width="100%" height="100%" align="baseline" id="Framework" src="" type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" codebase="../applets" archive=",jide-common.jar,jide-dock.jar,commons-codec-1.5.jar,init.jar,webtop.jar,navigation.jar,dem.jar,erp.jar,workflow.jar,jviews-gantt-all.jar,jviews-framework-all.jar,icu4j.jar" java_arguments="-Xmx512m" image="" code="com.ssaglobal.webtop.client.init.Webtop.class" mayscript="">
   <noembed>
&lt;DIV style='font-family:verdana'&gt;L'interface utilisateur d'Infor Web requiert un plugin Java 1.6 (ou une version ultérieure). Vous pouvez décharger ce plugin &lt;A href='http://java.com/download'&gt;ici&lt;/A&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;.
   </noembed>

</div>
</body>
```

I can't see any Selenium locators in order to pick specific elements whereas I expected them to appear by inspecting the page

Is there a way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's embedding a java app.  That would not be html.  That part of the page is running in the Java runtime at that point.

Comment: That's what I thought, would you suggest a workaround with Selenium ? I don't see any right now...

Comment: Selenium won't work.  Best thing would be to put the java in an IDE and automate white-box... if you can't do that the only thing that I can think of would be to use a Java Robot, but that would be a pain.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank you for the help !